# If Statement Using jQuery .hasClass Won't Work Properly

Tags: jquery, class, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to do different things when a `#box` element is hidden or visible, so I've made this script and attached to the `onClick` parameter of a show/hide button:

```
var box = null;

function showHide_Click() {
    box = $("#postBox").hasClass("hidden");

    if (box = true) {
        showBox();
        $("#postBox").removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
        hideBox();
    }
}
```

It works for showing the element, but the inverse won't work. What is wrong?

Comment: Do you want to use separate `postBox` and `box` ids (`$("#box").hasClass("hidden")` and `$("#postBox").removeClass("hidden")`)?

Comment: Sorry, both meant to be `#postBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example I would suggest you to use `jQuery` [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method which show/hide alternatively. Try this

```
function showHide_Click() {
    $("#postBox").slideToggle();
    $("#box").slideToggle();
}
```

FYI..The problem in your code was `box = true` which will not evaluate to any conditional check but will assign `true` to `box` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help(+1), but I have a little animation to show/hide the element, so I can't just use `.toggle`

Comment: You can use `slideToggle` to animate and toggle. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Wow! This helped a lot, I'm going to use this. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
box === true
```

or

```
if(box)
```

in place of

```
box = true
```

Comment: `box = true` is an assignment. `box === true` is a conditional expression.

Comment: I know it. I just said him to replace it.

Answer (score 2):

`box = true` assigns `true` to `box`, then `if`s the result (`true`)

You can just write `if (box)`, since it's already a boolean.

Had it not been a boolean, you would have neede to write

```
if (x === y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out your if statement. You either need a double equals, or remove it entirely to just say

```
if (box)
```